# How to fix the "Failed to connect to bus: Connection refused" problem?

Tags: reboot, dbus

When I try to reboot the system, it gives me a message:

```
my@comp:~$ sudo reboot
Failed to connect to bus: Connection refused
```

Maybe I broke some packages, but how to diagnose and fix it?

The system info is below

```
my@comp:~$ cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.04.3 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS"
VERSION_ID="16.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
VERSION_CODENAME=xenial
UBUNTU_CODENAME=xenial
```

Comment: FYI Ubuntu 16.04 is EOL and therefore off-topic here.

Comment: it was not back in 2017 @Esther

Comment: @Rinzwind true, but someone posted a bounty on this now. Not sure if they are using 16.04 or some newer version, and if they need an answer should they be posting a new question or expecting this one to get answers?

Comment: FWIW, I added the bounty because I'm experiencing the same issue on 18.04. `sudo systemctl status` gives "Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory" because /run and /var/run are two different dirs. I symlink /var/run/dbus to /run/dbus and get `Failed to connect to bus: Connection refused`.
There must be some way to signal to systemd to reset that connection to dbus.